# Deshabilitar interrupciones al visualizar un contador en 7 segmentos

Tags: arduino, esp32

He realizado un contador de 0 al 99 con 2 pulsadores. Un pulsador servirá para incrementar el contador y otro para decrementarlo. Ahora, estas acciones con los botones se realizaran mediante interrupciones, cosa que ya tengo implementado. Mi pregunta es: ¿Se puede desactivar momentáneamente las interrupciones cuando el valor del contador se muestran en los 7 segmentos? Cabe mencionar que estoy utilizando multiplexaje para imprimir el valor de los contadores en los 7 segmentos. He intentado ya interrumpir las interrupciones en la subrutina donde se encuentra el programa de impresión, pero el resultado es que ya no me deje incrementar el contador.

```
int outArray[]={D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7};
int count=0, unidades=0, decenas=0, unidades1=0, decenas1=0;
const int pulsadora=D0;
const int pulsadord=D1;
const int timeThreshold = 150;
long startTime_pm = 0; // Variable para el botón pm
long startTime_ph = 0; // Variable para el botón ph


void IRAM_ATTR handleInterrupta() {
 if (millis() - startTime_ph > timeThreshold) {
   unidades++;
 if(unidades>9)
 {
   unidades=0;
   decenas++;
 }
 if(decenas>9)
 {
   decenas=0;
 }

   startTime_ph = millis();
 }
}


void IRAM_ATTR handleInterruptd() {
 if (millis() - startTime_pm > timeThreshold) {
   unidades--;
 if(unidades<0)
 {
   unidades=9;
   decenas--;
 }
 if(decenas<0)
 {
   decenas=9;
 }

   startTime_ph = millis();
 }
}

void vizualiza()
{

unidades1= unidades +16;

for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{

digitalWrite(outArray[i], bitRead(unidades1, i));

}
delay(10);
decenas1=decenas+32;
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
digitalWrite(outArray[i], bitRead(decenas1, i));
}
delay(10);

}

void setup() {

pinMode(pulsadora, INPUT);
pinMode(pulsadord, INPUT);
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
 pinMode(outArray[i], OUTPUT);
}
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pulsadora),handleInterrupta,FALLING);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pulsadord),handleInterruptd,FALLING);

}

void loop() {

 vizualiza();
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*¿Se puede desactivar momentáneamente las interrupciones cuando el valor del contador se muestran en los 7 segmentos?*

Debes desactivarlas cuando *lees* los contadores.

El esquema general para compartir variables modificadas por una interrupción es el siguiente:

**Primero:** todas las variables compartidas se declaran con
`volative`:

```
volatile int unidades = 0;
volatile int decenas = 0;
```

Esto informa al compilador que el unidades y decenas pueden cambiar en cualquier momento. Por tanto, el compilador siempre lee el valor actual directamente de la variable.

Sólo necesitas aplicar `volatile` a las variables compartidas entre la interrupción y cualquier otro código externo. No tiene sentido en otros casos y hará más lenta la ejecución.

**Segundo:** Las variables compartidas deben ser copiadas a variables de trabajo con las interrupciones deshabilitadas:

```
  noInterrupts();         /* Deshabilita las interrupciones */
  unidades1 = unidades;
  decenas1 = decenas;
  interrupts();           /* Habilita las interrupciones */

  unidades1 += 16;        
  decenas1 += 32;
```

Como las interrupciones están deshabilitadas, el código debe limitarse a copiar los valores; cualquiera otra operación debe realizar fuera del bloque.

Una instrucción C como

```
  unidades1 = unidades;
```

se traduce en múltiples instrucciones de máquina en Arduino. Si se produce una interrupción mientras estas copiando el valor, puedes terminar obteniendo algo que no es ni el valor anterior ni el valor actual, sino una combinación de ambos.

**Tercero:** Copiar todas las variables al mismo momento para garantizar un juego consistente de valores.

Un problema en el código publicado es que la copia de unidades y decenas se hacen separadas en el tiempo:

```
unidades1 = unidades +16;

for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    digitalWrite(outArray[i], bitRead(unidades1, i));
    }

delay(10);
decenas1 = decenas+32;
```

Entonces se va a dar el siguiente caso:

1. El contador va en 9 unidades, 0 decenas.
2. Lees las unidades, obteniendo 9.
3. Mientras estas en el `delay()`, se produce otra interrupción, que cambia los contadores a 0 unidades, 1 decena.
4. Lees las decenas, obteniendo 1.
5. El display de 7 segmentos dice "19", error!.

Para evitar estas inconsistencias, copia todo al mismo tiempo.

**Código**

Además de cambiar `volatile` en las declaraciones, hay que aplicar estos cambios en `vizualiza`:

```
void vizualiza() {

  noInterrupts();
  unidades1 = unidades;
  decenas1 = decenas;
  interrupts();

  unidades1 += 16; // copia
  decenas1 += 32;

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

    digitalWrite(outArray[i], bitRead(unidades1, i));
  }
  delay(10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    digitalWrite(outArray[i], bitRead(decenas1, i));
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

No tengo hardware para probar, asi que no garantizo el resultado.